# Winform is disposed while still awaiting a task during the FormClosing event

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, dispose

I'm wanting to do some cleanup during the FormClosing event of a WinForm in a WinForms application. The cleanup code is async.

The FormClosing hander is:

```
private async void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    await DoCleanupAsync();

    // we never get here as the Form is disposed almost as soon as the async cleanup-method executes;
}
```

, with:

```
private async Task DoCleanupAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("stopping...");  // This is output
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("stopped");      // This is not
}
```

What's happening is the Form is being disposed of **before the await on the cleanup code is complete**.

Incidentally, this is causing a race condition where I'm trying to update the form (for simplicity let's say the form contains log output) during the cleanup and I get an ObjectDisposedException because the form has been disposed.

If I look at the callstack when Dispose() is called, I can see it's being triggered from

*System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown*

, so we can see that the dispose is being triggered directly from the FormClosing event, and nothing that I'm doing myself.

I can work around this by doing something hacky like:

```
private async void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    await DoCleanupAsync();
    this.FormClosing -= Form1_FormClosing;
    Close();
}
```

, but I'd like to understand what's actually going on!

Comment: Have you tried setting the flag on `e` to prevent closing before calling `DoCleanupAsync()`?

Comment: Of course. As soon as you reach _await_, the function returns and execution continues from where `Form1_FormClosing` was called. You seem to be thinking that execution halts until `DoCleanupAsync();` finishes, but that is not what `await`means.

Comment: You should read more about how that `async/await` stuff works. Then you'll find an answer by yourself.

Comment: The problem is that the event cannot / will not be awaited. So even if `DoCleanupAsync` is still running, the event has completed as far as the runtime is concerned. So the lifecycle of the form is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's actually going on

When you `await` an `async` method, the control flow returns to the caller of your `Form1_FormClosing` method. And when you didn't set the `e.Cancel` flag at this time, the form is closed.

The execution of your handler is resumed when the `Task` returned by `DoCleanupAsync` completed. But then the form is already closed.

Comment: Thanks -- silly me. I was assuming that the 'caller' of the Form-closing event would also be awaiting -- but that's obviously not possible given the return-type of void